# Exception handling using aws cognito in flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter

Where can I find documents about the AWS Exceptions that I might encounter when using functions in the Amplify.Auth package?

Or it's designed that I have to come back and handle the exception each time I discover a new one?

Comment: amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2 have you look at this? on pub. dev?

Comment: @ArbiterChil Thank you for your advise, but replacing the official SDK to an unofficial one wan't in my plan for now.

Comment: maybe looking at the repo of some package may help you to know how you can integrate the sdk itself

Comment: @ArbiterChil Sadly they only handle the SocketException and pack all the others exception as 'unknown error', which is not helpful in my case.  But thanks anyway.